# Unity Android Run Failed Due to Preconditions

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-analytics

I am trying to use the Google Analytics module with Android. With the same setup.
It work on desktop, but when i test it in phone android don't work. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/Preconditions;
at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzat.zzc(Unknown Source:0)
at com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source:0)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:151)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.koora.test-RHnaFDS1WgtEoEuT0vJRAg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.koora.test
```

Answer (score 1):

## The Solution:

I solved this issue by changing the version of the Android package "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics" from LATEST to 12.0.1.

This can be done by editing the file found at MyUnityProjectDirectory\Assets\GoogleAnalytics\Editor\GoogleAnalyticsDependencies.xml

Change the following line:

```
<androidPackage spec="com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:LATEST">
```

To

```
<androidPackage spec="com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1">
```

## Cause:

This issue seems to be caused by the absence of the dependencies of the latest version of the play-services-analytics -package in the configured repositories. Version 12.0.1 seems to be the latest version that has the required dependencies available with the same version number.

## Other information related to the issue:

This issue is preceded by a dependency resolution error while importing the Google Analytics Plugin for Unity. The error is easily left unnoticed.

You can re-do this resolution in Unity Editor by right clicking on the Assets-directory in the project hierarchy and then navigating to Play Services Resolver->Android Resolver->Force Resolve. This should result in a pop-up error message with a warning and an error in the console.

The warning:

```
Some conflicting dependencies were found.
The following dependency versions were modified:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1 --> com.google.android.gms:play- 
services-base:16.0.3
. . .
```

The error:

```
Resolution failed

Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.3@aar
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding packages via aar/jar files then just add `play-services-basement-16.0.1.aar`. You can find this file in [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-basement)

This basement package is part of play-services-location, so if you are adding aar file of location, this basement package is not included, which results in that error.

So basically if you add any other packages through aar, you have to check its pom file and see what all are its dependencies.